# Automapper map with constructor arguments

Tags: wpf, automapper

Updating my question since it was way to confusing.

I have 1 model object named Order.
I have two view models named OrderViewModel and OrderEntryViewModel.
I have an automapper mapping from Order to OrderViewModel.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderViewModel>();
```

I want OrderViewModel to have a reference to OrderEntryViewModel so I added it as a constructor argument to OrderViewModel:

```
public OrderViewModel(OrderEntryViewModel orderEntryViewModel)
{
    _orderEntryViewModel = orderEntryViewModel;
}
```

I map Order to OrderViewModel inside of the OrderEntryViewModel class, and during the mapping I'd like to pass that instance of OrderEntryViewModel to the generated OrderViewModel via the constructor, but I have no idea how to go about it using Automapper.

I've tried

```
Mapper.CreateMap(Order, OrderViewModel>().ConstructUsing(MyFunction);

public OrderViewModel CreateTest(Order o)
{
      return new OrderViewModel(this);
}
```

But it definately is not passing the instance of OrderEntryViewModel to the constructor.